# Rails one to many association with class_name problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, one-to-one

I have two models, User and Event. Every event has a unique admin who is a User role.
When I`m trying to access @event.admin i get my admin user but if I`m trying to access @user.administered_events to get the events this message is displayed.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'events.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (`events`.user_id = 5)

Rails is trying to access user_id from Event instead of admin_id. What I`m doing wrong?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administered_events, :class_name => "Event" 
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin, :class_name => "User"
end

class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.date :date
      t.string :status
      t.integer :admin_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the :foreign_key option when declaring your associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administered_events, :class_name => "Event", :foreign_key => "admin_id"
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin, :class_name => "User"
end
```

From the Rails documentation:

> By convention, Rails guesses that the
>   column used to hold the foreign key on
>   the other model is the name of this
>   model with the suffix _id added. The
>   :foreign_key option lets you set the
>   name of the foreign key directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administered_events, :class_name => "Event" , foreign_key => "admin_id"
end
```